# Executing installed batch file in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want the installer to create a service. I usually do this manually just by running the command prompt as an Administrator and going to the location of the `.bat` file and typing

```
service.bat install
```

Is there a way to execute this batch file inside an installer? If so, how? What do I add to my script? The location of this service file is `{the location of my installed app}\bin` and inside there is this `service.bat` file that needs to be executed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To execute a batch file in Inno Setup during installation, use the [`[Run]` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\bin\service.bat"; Parameters: "install"; Flags: runhidden
```