# execute batch file while installation javafx native build

Tags: java, javafx, installation, inno-setup

I am creating a setup using Javafx native bundle.

I have to perform some actions while installing the application.

I am able to add batch file in installation folder using this code.

```
<fx:resources>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                            includes="*.jar"/>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                            includes="lib/*.jar"/>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}"
                            includes="preference/*.*"/>
            </fx:resources>
```

But, my question is how can I execute the same file during installation?

As I know javafx uses Inno setup for the same.

So,I took a look at the [Executing installed batch file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651165/executing-installed-batch-file-in-inno-setup][1]).
But how can I add run entry using Javafx native build.

Comment: I see nothing in [the Ant task reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html) that indicates you can execute your own code upon installation.  Perhaps you can defer running your batch file until the first time the application runs?

Comment: Thank you. But, If i run the batch file at the time of running application it asks for permission. So it appears every time I open my application. So i chose to execute at while setup process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javapackager` is looking for a special file within the provided files (`deploy/windows/{yourproject-appname}.iss`). When having `verbose` set to `true`, you will get some message about some installer-files being put below your `%TEMP%`-folder. That file contains the special installer-creation files coresponding to your project. You will have to store that file with your project, as the temporary file folder is not used by the `javapackager` anymore.

To execute your batch-file after installation was succesfully, just modify your `.iss`-file you put into your project by adding the corresponding `[RUN]`-block.

For more information about that `[RUN]`-block just look at another [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654315/1961102) or at [the software documentation of Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall)